# What does "Om Sai Ram" mean?

Tags: rama, sai

I've seen this phrase/mantra – *Om Sai Ram* – written and uttered many times.

What does it mean?

Does 'Ram' over here mean Lord Rama? What do the rest of it and the whole thing mean?

Answer (score 2):

Om is pranav (brahman) according to vedas. Its hailed as shabd brahman.
As vedas say **ओमिति ब्रह्म।**
Om is Brahm

**राम रामेति परं जाप्यं तारकं ब्रह्म संज्ञकम्।** (Sanatkumar samhita)
Ram is also considered as shabd brahman.

**What about sai? Sai is just a Persian word meaning old.**

Now if you have to use word "to" but if it's said as 't+o' , does it make any sense? Absolutely no.

Exactly same thing is said in ram rahasya upanishad

**तारमायारंनगवावस्वबीजैश्च षड्विधः।
त्र्यक्षरो मंत्रराजः स्यात् अभीष्टफलप्रदः।।**

Before chanting "ram" six bija mantras are to be used.
Om, shrim, hreem kleem, aim, ram

Comment: Sir I've edited your answer a little. If you wish to rollback the edit, you can always 

Comment: साईं is tadbhava form for Svami. So you are effectively saying Om Swami Rama.

Comment: That doesn't mean you insult my bhagwan with name sai.